# Sorting an array of floats with qsort in C

Tags: c, floating-point, comparison, qsort

recently i've been trying to make a program which requires me to sort an array of structures that stores a string and the average ASCII value of the given string. I've been trying to sort it with the stdlib qsort, yet being relatively new to coding i've had onlyu some succes, as when in encounter equal averages for 2 strings i have to sort them alphabetically, otherwise they have to be sorted from the highest to the lowest.

My comparison function in the header of my qsort looks something like:

```
int struct_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct *pa;
    const struct *pb;
    pa = a;
    pb = b;
    if ( fabs(pa->average - pb->average) <= 0.000001 )
        return (strcmp(pb->text,pa->text));
    else
        return (pb->average - pa->average);
}
```

After sorting the array it looks like this:

```
85.166667
85.333333 
86.000000 
83.166667 
80.333333 
79.833333 
76.000000 
72.000000 
69.571429 
64.500000
```

Comment: It si not clear what is the expected result, maybe you want to post also the input that gives the output in the last line

Comment: Please post the *actual* compare function (the above code does not even compile).

Comment: `const struct *` isn't a valid type.

Comment: Why do you switch to using `strcmp` if the difference in averages is less than epsilon? `strcmp` doesn't compare numbers!

Comment: @IanAbbott right, which is why he's passing strings rather than numbers.

Comment: @TomKarzes sorry I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the final `return` to:

```
return pb->average > pa->average ? 1 : -1;
```

The problem with what you have is that it's converting a floating point value to an integer value, so if the difference is less than one, it is sometimes returning zero.